# Django server not responding

Tags: python, django

[image: Screenshot]

When I run `django-admin startproject newsite` in my root directory it works. But afterwards when i run `python manage.py runserver` in my cmd it doesn't give any results and opens the the new command line interface as it is:

```
C:\Users\Shiv Chandra Sraswat\Desktop\newsite>python manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

and there is no result. The answer that comes is

```
C:\Users\Shiv Chandra Sraswat\Desktop\newsite>
```

Can anyone tell what is the error ?
thank you

Comment: Please provide contents of C:\Users\Shiv Chandra Sraswat\Desktop\newsite folder.
It may be possible that you don't have manage.py file in that directory or manage.py file is empty

Answer (score 1):

Just run the server with `python manage.py runserver`

See here for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-runserver

Comment: the same cmd statement repeats.I am not getting my ip address for my website

Answer (score 0):

Just a test. Try to run your project from another folder, one that doesn't have white spaces in it.

For example:

```
C:\Users\ShivChandraSraswat\Desktop\newsite>
```

or

```
C:\Users\anotherUser\Desktop\newsite>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities

1. It may be possible that you don't have manage.py file in `C:\Users\ShivChandraSraswat\Desktop\newsite` directory
2. manage.py file is there but it is empty